# Launching a ViewController from an UIImagePickerController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, uiimagepickercontroller

## Problem

Upon returning to my UIImagePickerViewController from the view controller it launched, the camera screen forgets that the user took a picture and makes him retake one.

## Details

My camera has a 'share' button that is displayed both during the picture taking, and during the preview screen like so:

[image]

When share is clicked, the user is allowed to add contacts through another viewcontroller like so:

[image]

This is fine if the user does so before taking a picture, but if the user is on the preview screen, he is sent back to picture taking mode upon returning.

I've tried launching the new view controller both modally and by pushing/popping it, both however showed same behavior -- the imagepicker forgets it has already taken a picture.

## Possible Solutions

Is there a way to save the state of the imagepicker? Or maybe a way to display the other viewcontroller without having to launch it by itself? A solution that could work for now is simply not showing the share button during the preview screen.

Thank you SO.

Comment: Hi @Rob in your question it is not clear (at least to me) what the flow of your application is. Can you please try and clarify that? You have a view controller that launches the UIImagePickerViewController with the camera. I assume you are presenting that modally, is that correct? If so, once the camera is activated and visible, how to you present the "share" screen once that button is tapped?

Comment: Share, a uibutton added as the CameraOverlayView, launches the new Viewcontroller with `[imagePicker pushViewVontroller:tagsController animated:YES]`. I have also tried to launch it using `[imagepicker presentModalViewController:tagsController animated:YES]` but this had zero effect on the problem at hand.